# Parallel support using Jest with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I am using puppeteer for UI automation along with Jest as a test runner. I am able to run tests sequentially but i am facing an issue when running tests in parallel.
My page launch

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    //slowMo: 80,
    args: [`--window-size=${width},${height}`]
  });
  page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setViewport({width, height});
});

// and my tests are
test.concurrent("description", async () => {
  await page.goto('xxxx.com');
  //test code goes here
}, timeout)
test.concurrent("description ", async () => {
  //test code goes here
}, timeout)
```

I am getting following error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined
(node:9552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'addExpectationResult' of undefined
(node:9552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 3)
(node:9552) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.
regards,
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are facing this issue because the page variable is, as you are using arrow functions, just scoped to the beforeEach block. This block won't pass the in its defined variables to the test or describe blocks. I solved this by having a global variable for my tests and I added the page object to it with `global.PAGE = await browser.newPage()` in the test setup already. So before it is running the tests itself.

To check if this is the case you could simply try a `console.log(page);` inside your test.concurrent() block.

Have a look at the official jest documentation. They have already a working setup with jest and puperteer in place.

[>> Using jest with puppeteer](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/puppeteer.html)

Hope this helps.
cheers.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question: how to run a test in parallel with puppeteer.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple ways how you can run tests in parallel, by that I understand you run each test suite using new browser instance.

1. You can create new instance of browser in every `beforeAll` function 
   run, your tests and then close browser instance in `afterEach` function.

Example of simple test suite:

```
const browser;

    beforeEach(async () => {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch({}); //spinning up new browser instance
        page = await browser.newPage() 
        await page.goto('URL') 
    });

    test('test whatever', async () => {});
    test('test whatever2', async () => {});


    afterEach(async() => {
        await browser.close() //closes browser
    });
```

2. You can use [puppeteer with jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/puppeteer.html)

but you have to a but modify `PuppeteerEnvironment` class and for example do this that way

```
 async setup() {
        await super.setup();

        this.global.__BROWSER__ = await puppeteer.launch({});
    }
```

Thinks can be different depends what exactly you want to automate and how you structure your flow but remember to always every test much as possible independent from others.

I hope this will help you.